# How to see class structure window in addition to project window in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I can see the `structure` of a class in `IntelliJ` by `View --> Tool Windows --> Structure`, however, that replaces the existing `project` window (with the project hierarchy) on the left.

How can I see both windows, keep the project on the left, and the structure on the right with the editor sandwiched in between? That way I see where the class fits in the big picture on the left and the details of the class on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you open `structure`: left click the wheel -> Move to -> Right

Than Open `project` again.
This will give you the "sandwich" you wanted.

[image: moving 'structure' view to the right]

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the little settings wheel in the structure window's toolbar and select "Split Mode".

A little more intuitive way: Make the Toolbuttons visible (in the "View" menu) and just drag the "Structure" toolbutton down (or to another side).